# How do I configure Google-Guice using a generic interface?

Tags: java, guice

I have a bunch of entity type factories that derive from a common, generic interface. For instance,

```
public class ConnectionFactory implements IEntityFactory<Connection> { ... }
```

I'd like to use [Google-Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to break hard dependencies on these factories.

However, there's a syntax error when I try to configure Guice:

```
public class EntityFactoryModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IEntityFactory<Connection>.class).to(ConnectionFactory.class);
    }
}
```

Eclipse says "IEntityFactory cannot be resolved to a variable."

Can someone please help me understand why this doesn't work? Also, is there an alternate syntax that will work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My Guice-fu is generally limited, but I think you want a type literal here:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<IEntityFactory<Connection>>() {})
    .to(ConnectionFactory.class);
```

Comment: Nice, Guice-fu! Sadly, this yields an error "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)."

Comment: @retrodrone: I'd missed off the parentheses from the constructor call. Try the edited version, and see http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html for more details.

Comment: I should have known not to discount you, @JonSkeet, with that many badges. It seems to work, many thx for the link!

Comment: @JonSkeet, follow-up. Injector.getInstance() doesn't like the following syntax: this.entityFactory = entityFactoryInjector.getInstance(new TypeLiteral<IEntityFactory<Connection>>() {}); Do you know how to retrieve a concrete type?

Comment: @retrodrone: I believe you have to use `getProvider(Key.get(typeLiteral)).get()` in that case.

Comment: @retrodrone, @Jon: You can also do `getProvider(new Key<IEntityFactory<Connection>>(){})`.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to declare a new interface:

```
interface IConnectionFactory extends IEntityFactory<Connection> { ...}
```

Then I can do:

```
bind(IConnectionFactory.class).to(ConnectionFactory.class);
```

But, there's already an interface explosion going on in my project. 
Is there a better way?